Import trace for requested module & Module not found: Can't resolve 'private-next-rsc-action-client-wrapper'
I tried running an app I built with nextjs but it was showing multiple error, I have tried all I could.
Import trace for requested module:./app/(user)/(landing pages)/layout.tsx hydration-error-info.ts:72:9./lib/action.jsModule not found: Can't resolve 'private-next-rsc-server-reference'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-action-entry-loader.js?

./components/header/Header.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'private-next-rsc-action-validate'

./components/header/Header.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'private-next-rsc-server-reference'

My Next.Config File.

  config.resolve.alias = {
    '@components': path.join(process.cwd(), 'components'),
    '@lib': path.join(process.cwd(), 'lib'),
    '@models': path.join(process.cwd(), 'models'),
    '@public': path.join(process.cwd(), 'public'),
    '@opentelemetry/api': path.join(
       process.cwd(),
    'node_modules/next/dist/server/web/adapter.js'
     ),
  }
  return config;
}


 MY PACKAGE.JSON FILE
! {"name": "next-template","version": "0.1.0","private": true,"scripts": {"dev": "next dev","build": "next build","start": "next start","lint": "next lint"},"dependencies": {"@eslint/config-array": "^0.18.0","@eslint/object-schema": "^2.1.4","@opentelemetry/api": "^1.9.0","@react-pdf/renderer": "^3.4.4","@splidejs/react-splide": "^0.7.12","@uploadthing/react": "^6.7.2","aos": "^2.3.4","bcryptjs": "^2.4.3","class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0","clsx": "^2.1.1","date-fns": "^3.6.0","dotenv": "^16.4.5","firebase": "^10.8.1","lucide-react": "^0.427.0","mongoose": "^8.5.3","next": "^14.2.10","next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.20","react": "^18.3.1","react-dom": "^18","react-flags-select": "^2.2.3","react-hook-form": "^7.53.0","react-icons": "^4.10.1","react-loading-skeleton": "^3.4.0","react-pdf": "^9.1.0","react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.1","react-toastify": "^10.0.5","sharp": "^0.33.4","tailwind-merge": "^2.4.0","tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7","uploadthing": "^6.13.2"},"devDependencies": {"@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6","@types/node": "^20","@types/react": "^18","@types/react-dom": "^18","autoprefixer": "^10.0.1","eslint": "^8","eslint-config-next": "^0.2.4","postcss": "^8","tailwindcss": "^3.3.0","typescript": "^5"}} !


Please add details regarding the troubleshooting steps which you have performed.
